# Dead simple PHP issue on variables

Tags: php, variables

Just a simple question on syntax. To simplify:

```
$testme[0] = "hello";
$v = "me";
echo $test{$v}[0]; //expect this to output "hello"
```

Is there any way of writing the final line above such that "me" is referenced by a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
echo ${'test' . $v}[0];
```

instead